# Scrollbars are not appearing in FF but on Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, scrollbars

recently I found a link and opened it in FF and in Chrome.
A small PopUp appeared. I resized the PopUp in Chrome and scrollbars appeared.
Then I resized the PopUp in FF and I wasn't able to scroll. There were no scrollbars.

Is it a known issue or does it have to do with some styles?
The scrollbars are just appearing in Chrome when the window gets to small to read the whole text, but not in FF.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities. Which link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website open a new window with javascript. The code is the following:

```
<a class="white" href="javascript:popupNoScrollbars('/casino/popupOperatedBy.faces','Tipico Casino Ltd.',620,620)">Operated by Tipico Casino Ltd.</a>
```

The code for function `popupNoScrollbars`

```
function popupNoScrollbars(url, name, width, height) {
   name = name.replace(/ /g,"");
   name = name.replace(/./g,"");
  popwin = window.open(url,name,"toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,status=no,width="+width+",height="+height+",dependent=yes");
  popwin.focus();
}
```

Probably the above function breaks in Chrome, with result to show the scrollbars when you resize but works correctly in firefox (without scrollbars in resize).

If you add the address in firefox, without opened by javascript, you will see that the scrollbars works
https://www.tipico.com/casino/popupOperatedBy.faces